# Scroll View doesn't scroll to top - Android

Tags: java, android, scroll, scrollview

I am trying to scroll to the top of my `ScrollView`, and I am using the below and both types it works a little over **50%** the other time sit just stays where it is

```
private void focusOnView(){
    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            sv.scrollTo(0, sv.getTop());
        }
    });
}
```

And the other way I am doing it

```
sv.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "TOP TOP");
            sv.scrollTo(0, sv.getTop());
        }
    });
```

THnaks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this

```
sv.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "TOP TOP");
            sv.scrollTo(0, 0);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
sv.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        sv.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
    }
});
```

If you want to scroll to bottom, using FOCUS_DOWN.